# Why is my array_diff usage breaking things?

Tags: php, array

On my WordPress site, I usually only have one tag per post.

However, I now have some posts that have a second tag, "expired", that I use for another purpose.

So I need to adjust my code below to remove that "expired" tag before I process the one tag left.

It looks like I should be able to use array_diff to remove the "expired" tag, based on my reading of php.net and some other stack exchange posts.

However, when I tried to implement that, I'm getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to a string

Can you show me where I'm going wrong here? :)

```
    //get topic (tag)
        global $post;       
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $entry_id = FrmDb::get_var( 'frm_items', array( 'post_id' => $post_id_here ), 'id' ); //get entry id
        $topic = get_the_tags($post_id); //get topic (tag) 
    
    /*at this point, $topic contains (for example):
 
 Array (
    [0] => WP_Term Object (
        [term_id] => 155 
        [name] => expired 
        [slug] => expired 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 155 
        [taxonomy] => post_tag 
        [description] =>  
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 25  
        [filter] => raw 
    )
    [1] => WP_Term Object (

        [term_id] => 154 
        [name] => Memorial Day Sales 
        [slug] => memorial-day-sales 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 154 
        [taxonomy] => post_tag 
        [description] =>  
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 1 
        [filter] => raw 
    )
) 

*/

//now the line that is causing a problem
    
        $topic = array_diff($topic, ["expired"]); //remove expired tag if an expired post
    
    //
        $topic = $topic[0]->name; //should only be one
        $topic_url = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $topic)));
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
        $img_url = $image_src[0]; // image url
            if (!empty($topic)) {
    $see_more = '<div id="topic"><a href="https://example.com/topic/'.$topic_url.'/">See more from our '.$topic.'</a></div>';
            }
            else $see_more = "";
```

Comment: What's in `$topic` just before you try the `array_diff()` on it? (Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/409685/edit) if you're providing an answer to this; you can't format anything in comments, and it's super hard to read a `var_dump()` of an array, for example.)

Comment: It would be an array of wordpress tags, for example, "father's day" and "expired". I want to remove the "expired". Sometimes it might just have the tag "expired", in which I need the result to be empty afterwards.

Comment: Added the array to the question, sorry, came out as one long line

Comment: OK, the issue is that `$topic` is an array of `WP_Term` objects, and you can't match the string `expired` to the term object.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the Fatal Error because `array_diff()` is comparing the `WP_Term` objects in your array to a string, and it can't do that. Here's one way to fix that:

Replace

```
$topic = array_diff($topic, ["expired"]);
```

with:

```
$my_topic = array();
foreach ( $topic as $term ) {
    if ( 'expired' !== $term->slug ) {
        // Adds $term to my topic if it's not 'expired'.
        $my_topic[] = $term;
    }
}
// $my_topic is the new $topic.
$topic = $my_topic;
```

Comment: Super - thank you so much for your help with this! Working flawlessly and furthers my limited understanding of how arrays work.